# JavaScript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: j is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
j('a.icon_job').each(function() {
    var lnk = 'http://www.bullhornreach.com' + j(this).attr('href');
    j(this).attr('href', lnk).attr('target', '_blank');
})
```

Could you help me please?

My JavaScript code above shows this error:

> Uncaught `ReferenceError`: `j` is not defined

and the URL is not working in new window.

Preview URL in here: http://acumentalentsearch.com/job-listings-2/

Comment: Try replacing `j` with `jQuery` or add `var j = jQuery.noConflict();` at the top of the code.

Comment: You have `<script type="text/javascript" id="sns_scripts_in_head"><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script></script>`, which is an invalid syntax

Comment: you mean jQuery('a.icon_job').each(function() {
    var lnk = 'http://www.bullhornreach.com' + jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery(this).attr('href', lnk).attr('target', '_blank');
})

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr, Tushar... its working now